# Why it remains only one digit after point in this numerical computation?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

Why? And why `N` doesn't help?

[image]

How to change and/or make it permanent?

Comment: Mathematica has several different kinds of numbers. And it has rules about how those numbers are displayed. Mathematica thinks 4352982 is an exact integer and will display all digits of exact integers. But Mathematica thinks 0.00460 is an approximate decimal number. The product of exact and approximate will always be approximate. Approximate numbers are displayed with about 6 digits total. If you tell `N[approximateNumber,1000]` it thinks that is only an approximate number and won't make up another 995 digits for you. N[4352982*460/10^5,1000] will find an exact result and display those

Comment: Can I force using more digits in "approximate" numbers without switching to exacts? Mathematica treats them not as usual in Physics, for example `4352982.00000000000000*0.004600000000000000` still evaluetes to 6 digits, although there are explicitly specified much more meaningful digits.

Comment: There are several things competing with each other. One is how you tell Mathematica what the precision is. The other is the rules for displaying the result. Try reading https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html And try entering 4352982*0.00460\`40  Note that \`40 is a shorthand to tell MMA that number has 40 digits of precision, but I am not certain that will do what you are really looking for. And I'm not certain there is a "do what I mean" button you can push that will make Mathematica permanently start doing and displaying all numbers the way you want.

Comment: If you want 20 digit precision, you need to to specify real numbetrs in the the input with at least 20 digit precision like z.B.: `N[4352982  0.0046000000000000000000, 20]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make sure that Mathematica knows that `0.00460` is accurate to 20 digits of precision, you can use the `` ` `` suffix followed by the number of digits of precision:

```
4352982*(0.00460`20)

(* 20023.717200000000000 *)
```

As noted in the comments, Mathematica treats `4352982` as an exact integer with arbitrary precision, so you don't need to use the suffix `` ` `` on that number.  If you have two decimal numbers that you want to specify the precision of, you would need to do something like

```
4352982.0`20*(0.00460`20)
```

As an aside, if you were in my first-year physics class, I would insist that the number `0.00460` really should only be treated as having three digits of precision, and the answer should be `2.00*10^4` instead.  But that's as may be.